# Is this chemical name wrong? 2-bromobutane vs 1-bromobutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Well, technically it's already wrong because it should end in "-propane" but my textbook is so crappy let's just ignore that for a second. The naming convention goes that substituent groups should be named so that they have the lowest number possible. Then, in both of the bromopropanes below, shouldn't they both be 1-bromopropane because there are no other substituent groups besides the bromine?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0bRe.png]

Comment: I completely don't get your question.

Comment: @Mithoron since we're supposed to number the substituent with the smallest one we can give it (whether we read the carbon chain's numbering left-to-right or right-to-left, in the above example), can't we write 1-bromobutane as the name for the 2-bromobutane if we just read the carbon chain from right-to-left?

Comment: @MaxLi No. The bromine is not on the first carbon, regardless of which direction you number it from.

Answer (score 2):

The numbering of locants in the question is correct. In acyclic hydrocarbons, the longest chain is numbered from one end to the other.

[image: 1-bromopropane]    [image: 2-bromopropane]

The corresponding subsection of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-15.1.7.1.4** The longest chain is numbered from one end to the other by arabic numbers, the direction being chosen so as to give the lower locants to the substituent groups (side chains) [see P-14.4(f)]. (…)